# Is there a way to have nested v-data-table in Vuetify 3?

Tags: vuejs3, vuetifyjs3, v-data-table, vuetify-datatable

Well if you see this, you probably have a similar problem then I had
I fixed mine by just looking into the official docs for the umptenth time [Expand v-data-table](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/basics/#expandable-rows). I just missed that part.
And this expandanble data-table row was not my solution for displaying my data. Hope it'll do for you

---

I'm currently struggling in finding a suitable approach to display hierarchical data in Vuetify 3 (3.4.0).

Despite my efforts, I encountered issues such as errors and the second table not being rendered as expected. I've explored various methods, including those used in Vuetify 2, searched for relevant packages on [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/), and attempted solutions involving treeview packages. Unfortunately, my attempts with pure code have been unsuccessful, and even after seeking assistance on Stack Overflow, none of the discovered answers have resolved my specific problem.

If anyone has insights or suggestions on how to effectively implement hierarchical data display in Vuetify 3 (3.4.0), I would greatly appreciate the guidance. Thank you!